# Accessing enviroment variables through nuxt application when hosted on heroku

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I have built a Nuxt application that uses a .env file to provide a secret key to my server middleware .js file using the @nuxtjs/dotenv module.

Everything works as expected in development and production mode but when I deploy my project to heroku the enviroment variables are undefined.

I have added the config vars to heroku but still no luck. I have managed to deploy a simple express app and access the config vars for practice but there is something going on with nuxt that I just can't figure out.

Please help :o(

Comment: did you figure it out? I'm also stuck on the same problem